# Quantum analogue to pointwise mutual information

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, quantum-information, entropy

Mutual information in statistical mechanics has been generalized to quantum systems as quantum mutual information. Does pointwise mutual information also have an analogue in quantum statistical mechanics? If so, how is it estimated, and how is it used?